# Backbone Events on jquery tool tip

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery-tooltip

I'm using JQuery Tool Tip in on my HTML page and in that tool tip I've User Name and a Sign Out Link.

Now I'm trying to bind the event in my backbone view, on the id of the Sign Out Link.
But the event is not fired.

I removed the tool tip code and then when i clicked on the sign out link  the event got fired.

So question here is - Is it possible to bind the backbone event on jquery tool tip? If not than what would be the work around.

Some code snippets

This is the function which is used to apply jquery tool tip

```
jQuery(function () {
                jQuery.widget("ui.tooltip", jQuery.ui.tooltip, {

                    options: {
                        content: function () {
//                          self.addDescendant('toolTip', {selector: templ.loginHelpContent, view: tt});
                            return jQuery(templ.loginHelpContent).html();
                        },
                        show: null, 
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            ui.tooltip.hover(

                            function () {
                                jQuery(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
                            },

                            function () {
                                jQuery(this).fadeOut("400", function () {
                                    jQuery(this).remove();
                                })
                            });
                        },
                        position: {
                            my: "left-190 bottom-18",
                            using: function( position, feedback ) {
                                jQuery( this ).css( position );
                                jQuery( "<div>" )
//                              .addClass( "arrow" )
                                .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                                .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                                .appendTo( this );
                            }
                        },
                    }                       
                });
                jQuery(templ.loginHelpIcon).tooltip();
            });
```

and the HTML

```
<span id=loginHelpContent style="display:none">
                        Not Elizabeth Murphy? <a id="logoutLink" style="color:blue;text-decoration: none">Sign out</a><br> and login as a different user.
                    </span>
```

When I tried to bind and event on 'logoutLink' it didn't worked.

Comment: Some code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the "tooltipopen" event `".tooltip tooltipopen": "listenTooltip"` and in listenTooltip function :

```
listenTooltip: function( e ) {
    var tooltip = $( e )
}

 Now you can bind listener to tooltip in this function
```